# Copy-Paste values in the vertex editor table

Tags: qgis, coordinates, editing, vertices, paste

I have some polygons with z values for each node. However, there are a great number of nodes that don't have a value. I have to fill these nodes with a value, but I don't want to copy paste for each cell. So is there a faster way to paste z values in the vertex editor?

[image]

Comment: Do these vertices have the same z value? I guess they do as they form the same polygon.

Comment: No, sometimes they don't. These polygons represent crops or forest areas and the terrain is not always flat. Some points in the polygon may have the same z value but not all of them. I have lots of polygons, each one with different z values also. At the office a programmer has designed a QGIS tool that gives a z value for each point, but sometimes there are mistakes and we have to correct z values manually. I was asking if there is a faster way of filling the table rather than copying and pasting a value one by one